# Debian doesn't obey umask on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, umask

I have been reading a bunch of posts here and at server fault about the umask an debian but I still don't compeltely understand what's going on with it.

Here's my problem, tell me what I'm doing wrong:

I'm on my machine and i type umask:

```
aknapp@ftp2-atl:~$ umask
0002
```

Again with -S:

```
aknapp@ftp2-atl:~$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

Now if I touch a file, it doesn't have the right permissions for the given umask.  WTF?

```
aknapp@ftp2-atl:~$ touch me
aknapp@ftp2-atl:~$ ls -l me
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aknapp aknapp 0 Mar  2 14:51 me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html. Umask for files and directories is calculated differently